# as.Date gives na because of mixed formats in .txt file

Tags: r, date, format

I have a text file which contains 300k rows, it has a column X_NOMIN_DT which has mixed formats like below :

```
X_NOMIN_DT
02-02-2011
12/23/2010 0:00
12/23/2010 0:00
12/22/2010 0:00
12/23/2010 0:00
12/23/2010 0:00
8/15/2010 0:00
08-01-2010
08-10-2010
9/30/2012 0:00
9/29/2012 0:00
```

I have tried as.Date with format, POSIX function etc.. But, no matter what I do, i still get NA values..

The values are in Character format, Can someone help me to convert them to Date format in R.

Comment: Using the `lubridate` package: `X_NOMIN_DT2 <- parse_date_time(X_NOMIN_DT, orders = c("m-d-y","m/d/y H:M"))`

Comment: @tifu Awesome, Thanks a lot..